# How to ignore the first yield value?

Tags: python, redis

The following code is for illustrative purposes only.

```py
def get_messages_from_redis():
    for item in self.pubsub.listen():
        yield (item['channel'], item['data'])  # how to ignore the first yield?
```

I know the following way can ignore the first yield value:

```py
g = get_messages_from_redis()
next(g)
```

But how to ignore this in `get_messages_from_redis()`?
(counter can be used to control whether to yield, but is there a better way?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate inside your function before yielding. I'm not sure what your iterable is exactly, but here's a generic example assuming a `list`.

```py
def get_messages_from_redis():
    for item in self.pubsub.listen()[1:]:
        yield item['channel'], item['data']
```

For a more universal solution, you could create an iterator of your iterable, iterate over the first one, then loop and yield from there. **Note:** This is mostly for broader coverage, I'm not sure what negative consequences this might have with certain iterables.

```py
def iter_skip_first(i):
    iterable = iter(i)
    next(iterable)

    for i in iterable:
        yield i

li = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {"one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3, "four": 4}

print(*iter_skip_first(li))
print(*iter_skip_first(d))
```

Comment: `iter_skip_first` can just return `iterable` instead of looping over it, for one less level of indirection.

Comment: Excellent point! I'll edit that. **Edit:** Never mind, the example is still prudent here since you lose the other benefits of yield by exiting the function and it wouldn't address the original question.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could help.